# Proof of CZK funds for a visitor visa to Canada

Tags: canada, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I need to submit bank statements for a visitor visa to Canada. Since I live in Prague, Czech Republic, all my transactions in the statement as well as the account balance info are in CZK (in Czech currency). I was wondering if that would be a problem? Do I need to provide some paper indicating the equivalent of my funds in CAD/US dollar?

Comment: I don't think the title reflects the question very well, would you mind editing it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to supply the exchange rate between your currency and Canada's currency (or any other country you might apply for a visa). Exchange rates are public information available to anyone on the Internet, and they will simply look it up themselves.